# Javascript : How to analyze potential DOM changes constantly?

Tags: javascript

I am making an extension for an online chat that has to count the number of new messages sent since the user entered the tchat.
So I'm looking for a JavaScript function that can analyse permanently the tchat page content  (specifically the div that contains all messages) and then execute a function. This function will modify the logo badge of the extension and put the number of new messages instead.
I've already tried with MutationObserver, but it doesn't work (maybe because I made mistakes, I don't know). Here's my manifest.json :

```
{
"manifest_version":2,
"name":"Tchat",
"description":"test",
"version":"0.0.2",
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["page-reader.js"],
    "persistent": true
},

"commands":{
  "_execute_browser_action":{
    "suggested_key":{
      "default":"Ctrl+Q"
    }
  }
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_popup":"index.html",
    "default_icon": {               
      "16": "images/favicon-16x16.png",
      "32": "images/favicon-32x32.png", 
      "144": "images/android-icon-144x144.png"
    }
},

"icons": {
    "16": "images/favicon-16x16.png",
    "32": "images/favicon-32x32.png", 
    "144": "images/android-icon-144x144.png"            
}
}
```

Here's my page-reader.js file :

```
var targetNode = null;
var config = {
attributes: true,
childList: true,
subtree: true
};
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
var numberOfTchatMessages = 0;
var observer = null;

function tchatAnalyser() {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
    let url = tabs[0].url;

    if (url == "here is the tchat url") {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "red"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "ON"});

        targetNode = document.getElementById('zone_tchat');


        var callback = function() {
            numberOfTchatMessages++;
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: numberOfTchatMessages.toString()});
        };


        if (targetNode && MutationObserver) {
            observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
            observer.observe(targetNode, config);
        }
    }

    else {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:"dodgerblue"});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:"OFF"});
    }
});
}

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(tchatAnalyser);
```

The logo gets red when I switch to the chat tab, but the text stays at ON… Is there any error in my code ? Is MutationObserver the tool I need ?

Thank you in advance, have a nice day,

Comment: Yes, [Mutation Observer](https://javascript.info/mutation-observer) is the tool you need.

Comment: @Mushroomator OK, thank you. So, I think there is a mistake in my code so that the number of messages is not displayed on the extension badge, right?

Comment: OK so I think I know what the problem is. I added to my page-reader.js a line: console.log(targetNode). In the extension console the code wrote null, I think it's because the script was executed in the background-page extension instead of the chat page window (I am sure the element zone_chat exists, I already got it in the browser built-in console). Do you know how to solve this problem?